# Angular Material Datepicker Highlight Range Week Start to Week End

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material2

**I need users to pick a beginning week and an ending week since the data being returned in a range of start week to end week.**

[image: Material Datepicker Range Example]

I am attempting to highlight the **entire week on any date picked on start date** range and highlight the **entire end week selecting the last day in the end week**.

I am using a date range picker and the highlight works fine and inputs the start day of the week and the last day in the end week... but i cant understand how to highlight it in the picker. Instead, the picker shows the mid week day a the start of the selected dates not the beginning day of thee week/

I want my users to select a start and end week.

I have created a dateClass and a method but i am unable to set the week range to a color.

##### Reproduction

Here's the stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ucvaay?file=src/app/date-range-picker-overview-example.html

Steps to reproduce:

1. Click the calendar - click a date that is not a weekend or the beginning day of the week
2. the input will update the value to the beginning day of the week and when an end day is selected it will get the last day in the end date week (as expected)
3. The issue: Open the datepicker again and notice that highlighted date range does not include the beginning days (entire week highlighted nor the end week highlighted.

I need users to pick a beginning week and an ending week since the data being returned in a range of start week to end week.

Any idea on how to get the start and end week to select like the range selection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a FormGroup to your datepicker which gives you the ability to change the values of the start and end date. In your dateRangeChange()-method you could then update the selected values to the beginning and end of the week. I added the functionality to your Stackblitz-project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ucvaay-8brpty?file=src/app/date-range-picker-overview-example.ts

Comment: This is pretty much what i want except i want users to select a week not a day. Is this possible @StippeJ?

Comment: Actually i removed the if condition that checks if both values are present and it works. Thanks so much - i didn't realize form control was what activated the update of the dp. You're awesome!